# Efficiently count ngrams by ID in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of 10,000 ngrams (more than 1 word phrases) and 6.5M records with varying amounts of text (ranging from 10 characters to 5,000 characters). I wish to create 10,000 new columns in my dataframe that each contain a count of the associated ngram. My current solution involves looping through the column in the dataframe with the text, count the number of times the ngram shows up in each row using re.findall, put the length of the findall method in a list, and use the list to create the new column in the dataframe.

Because of memory constraints, I am paging through the data 100,000 (of the 6.5M) rows at a time. It takes about five hours to get through a page where the final result is a dataframe that contains the original columns plus the 10,000 columns (one for each ngram). Since I have 65 pages to get through, I expect it would take 325 hours to get through all of it.

Is there a better way to do this? I tried to find a numpy vectorization approach but came up empty.

Edit: After working with this some more, I've started using Pandas vectorization

```
ngram = 'hello world'
df["columnCnt"] = df["text_column"].str.count(ngram)
```

I am looping through a list of 10,000 ngrams and calling str.count for each of the 10,000. Is there a way to vectorize this so that all 10,000 are done faster than looping?

Comment: A different way (but not necessarily better/faster) would be to loop over text instead of looping over ngrams, updating e.g. a counter object keeping the tallies, then finding the intersection of the found ngrams with your list. Obviously if the ngrams are not fixed length (e.g. all ngrams up to 3grams) then this will be less and less efficient.

Comment: I'm down from around two weeks of runtime to 1 day with the pandas vectorization. This is much better but I'm still interested in whether there is a faster way.

Comment: I believe your method would be O(N*W) where N is the number of Ngrams, W number of words, while what I propose is O(W)+O(N)

Comment: Are you proposing that I create a list of lists where each sublist contains 10,000 elements (one for each ngram), and I end up with 6.5M sublists? If so, how would I do that? Could you answer with some code that I can accept? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Nah I'm saying to generate all ngrams (all 1grams, all2grams till some limit; this assumes that your ngrams are all within some small range like that. If your ngrams include long ngrams with short (eg a 10gram or 20gram here and there then my proposal wont work).)

Answer (score 1):

This will count all 1,2,3grams for instance in the  phrase:

```
from collections import defaultdict
phrase='worms in the belly of the leviathan. we the living bear the cross of history when in the company of dogs it behooves one to act like a dog'

allwords = phrase.split()
ngram_dict = defaultdict(int)
for n in [1,2,3]:
 for i in range(len(allwords)-n):
     words=' '.join([allwords[i+j] for j in range(n)])
     ngram_dict[words]+=1
```

Then find the intersection of your list with the ngrams above .

```
ngrams_to_detect=['worms','dogs','worms in','act like','monster trucks']
detected=set(ngram_dict.keys())
relevant_detected = detected.intersection(ngrams_to_detect)
Out[92]: {'act like', 'dogs', 'worms', 'worms in', 'the'}

not_found = set(ngrams_to_detect)-relevant_detected
Out[93]: {'monster trucks'}
```

There's some tradeoff here of how complete your list is and how much time is wasted above generating irrelevant ngrams.  The counts can be returned by:

```
detected_counts = {k:v for k,v in ngram_dict.items() if k in relevant_detected}
Out[100]: {'worms': 1, 'dogs': 1, 'worms in': 1, 'act like': 1, 'the': 5}
```